# Number each list element and format text in haskell

Tags: haskell, numbers, element

I want to give each one a number from 1 to length(x:xs), like a book's page number. Unfortunately it only works backwards.

```
numberL :: [String] -> [String]
numberL [] = []
numberL (x:xs) = ([show (length(x:xs)) ++ ": " ++ x] ++ numberL (xs))
```

Also how do I remove any new line and tab from the text and replace it with the actual new line and tabulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple built-in Haskell functions in `Prelude` that are good to learn and use them. `zip` and `zipWith` are two of them, when you think about something to be done using two different lists into one result list:

`[1..]`  will generate the list of indices for you, it's an infinite list

```
appendIndex :: String -> Int -> String
appendIndex s i = (show i) ++ " :" ++ s

indexThem :: [String] -> [String] 
indexThem l = zipWith appendIndex l [1..]
```

if you wanted to use `zip`, which is more basic but a little more verbose:

```
appendIndex :: (String,Int) -> String
appendIndex (s,i) = (show i) ++ " :" ++ s

indexThem :: [String] -> [String] 
indexThem l = fmap appendIndex $ zip l [1..]  
-- if you dont know about Functors yet, `fmap` is the generic way of doing `map`
```

Answer (score 3):

To get it right, it's important to understand why you're thinking wrong. Your recursion looks like this:

```
numberL (x:xs) = ... ++ numberL xs
```

So you calculate `numberL xs` and then put something in front of it. If  `numberL xs` were correct, then then it would be numbered from 1 onwards, like: `1:..., 2:..., 3:...`. So you could never build `numberL (x:xs)` from `numberL xs` just by adding new elements at the front. The whole numbering would be wrong. Instead you'd have to change the whole numbering of `numberL xs`.

The problem therefore is that it's not very useful to know `numberL xs` in order to calculate `numberL (x:xs)`, due to the fact `numberL` always starts numbering from 1.

So lift that restriction. Build a function that numbers starting at `n`,

```
numberLFrom :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
numberLFrom n []     = ...
numberLFrom n (x:xs) = ...
```

Now the question you have to ask yourself is, in order to number `(x:xs)` starting at `n` you need to number `xs` starting at which number? And then how do you introduced the numbered `x` to that result?